# FQL page_fan - the query returns no result

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, facebook, facebook-fql

On this Facebook query:

```
"SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me() and page_id = " + page_id
```

Is the "user_likes" permission required from Facebook to run the query? I'm just wondering if this is the reason it is not working? It always returns "the user has not liked the page".

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that query would never return "the user has not liked the page". I'm guessing your code is returning that string.

Yes you need user_likes permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the `user_likes` permission to request the like info from the `page_fan` FQL table.

You can test this by using the Graph Explorer:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_fan%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29)

Test Cases:

1. Request Access Token without `user_likes` permission -> Nothing is shown (empty data array)
2. Request Access Token with `user_likes` permission -> The list of the actual User's likes is shown